# Orientation preserving mappings

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I came across the following question: Let $Y=\{(r,\theta,\phi)\in \mathbb R^3:0\leq r<\infty , 0\leq\theta<2\pi, 0\leq \phi\leq\pi \}$ and let $f:Y\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ such that $f(r,\theta,\phi)=(r\cos\theta\sin\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\phi)$. Show that $f$ preserves orientation. My attempt: the jacobian of $f$ is just $r^2\sin\phi$ and we need to show that it is greater then $0$ for all $r$ and $\phi$. It is obvious that for $r>0$ and $\phi\not\in \{0,\pi\}$ we will get that $f$ preserves orientation since $r^2\sin\phi>0$, but what about the boundary points (i.e. $r=0$ or $\phi\in\{0,\pi\}$) ?

Comment: Yes, the mapping is degenerate when $\phi = 0,\pi$ or $r=0$, and, strictly speaking we should work on an open set, so $0<\theta<2\pi$. But, more seriously, in the order you've given the variables, I believe the mapping is *not* orientation-preserving. You need to reverse $\phi$ and $\theta$. Double-check your work.